# *** stack smashing detected *** in a C++ array program

Tags: c++

I'm writing a simple program which simulates a real world physics problem about electron spin.
It should fill an array of 10 with 1 or -1 randomly. then for 100 times choose one element and do the following conversion based on it's neighbors:

```
+-+ ..... +++
-+- ..... ---
+++ ..... +++
--- ..... ---
```

and in the following cases randomly pick a result:

```
-++ ..... --+ or -++
--+ ..... --+ or -++
+-- ..... ++- or +--
```

etc

but when i run it i get this error:
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
Aborted (core dumped)

I checked and it's on the last "else" two lines. it doesn't give error when i comment them.

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arr[10],a[2],i,curr,next,prev,j;
    double r;
//Fill arr[10] with random -1 & 1
    a[0]=-1; a[1]=1;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        r=rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0)*2.0;
        arr[i]=a[int(r)];       
    }
//Cout arr[10]
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<'\n';
//Repeat for 100 times
    for(j=1;j<=100;j++){
        r=rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0);
        r=(r)*11;
        curr=int(r);
        next=(curr+1)%11;
        prev=(10+curr)%11;
        if(arr[prev]==arr[next]){
            if(arr[prev]==1)arr[curr]=1; else arr[curr]=-1;
        }
        else
        {
            r=rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0)*2.0;
            arr[curr]=a[int(r)];
        }
    }
//Cout arr[10]
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `prev=(10+curr)%11;` has possible value between `[0-10]`. But in C, array index begins at 0 so if arr has 10 elements, possible index are `[0-9]`. So `arr[prev]` could be out of bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    r=(r)*11;
    curr=int(r);
    //...
    arr[curr]=//...
```

`r` can take a value of 10.X at low probability, causing `curr` to take the value of 10, assigning to `arr` at 10, which corrupts memory.

Comment: It's seems just right! when I define arr[11] instead of [10] error fixes. how can I fix it without destroying the equal chance for all array elements to be selected?
(I guess making it r*10 doesn't have equal chance for all elements)

Comment: True, r*10 doesn't make equal probability for all elements, but neither does r*11! Getting equals requires powers of 2 and rerolling when out of range if you need a non-power-of-2 limit.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add a 'if' to prevent r==10 scenario.

Comment: You can check out http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random and more specific http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution for better random handling.

Comment: The why _stack smashing_ should be addressed, especially for those who are just getting into c++. In this case, stack smashing occurs because `arr` is an array that is created on the stack rather than allocated from the heap. The important aspect is the out-of-range memory write, but to understand stack smashing, why the compiler protects against it, and c++ memory usage in general, see these links; [stack smashing](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html),  [memory](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_memory_and_heaps.html) for a good starter on the subject (no affiliations).